# Push SVG String into Dom?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a javascript variable that basically looks like this:

```
my_svg_image = '<circle cx="227.58331298828125" cy="102" r="3" style="fill:black;stroke-width:0" />';
```

It was loaded from my database.  Is there a way I can parse that string and add it to the DOM with Javascript?  I have svgweb set up, but don't see how I can get it to parse this string.  Are there other libraries that might help?

Comment: The DOM you are referring: is it inline or embedded svg in html - or standalone svg?

Comment: Sorry, I want to render the image described with the string onto the page.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried javascript's [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp) property?

edit: You can only use innerHTML property for html elements, so you can use a string containing a whole svg image to add it to an html element. But you cannot add a svg element to an existing svg element.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0 plus SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/2002/04/xhtml-math-svg/xhtml-math-svg.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <![CDATA[    
    function test() {
        var newsvg = document.getElementById("svg-wrapper");
        var svgstr = '<svg:svg height="300" width="700" id="svg-container"><svg:circle cx="150px" cy="100px" r="30px" /></svg:svg>';
        newsvg.innerHTML = svgstr;
    }   
   ]]>
   </script>
   <title>SVG DOM</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="svg-wrapper"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:test();" value="generate svg"/><br/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

If you want to add a circle to existing inline SVG, you have to add it using DOM methods (and the prbably first parse your string to extract the needed attribute values).

Comment: More descriptive...what tag should I add it within?

Answer (score 1):

I was recently looking for something similar to this, but I needed to update part of an existing SVG, so using innerHTML wasn't an option for me. I ended up taking a look at how Canvg pulls it off and came up with this:

```
var $contentToReplace = $('svg .some-class');
$contentToReplace.empty();

var content = new DOMParser().parseFromString(newContent, 'text/xml');

// content.children is an HTMLCollection, so using Array.prototype.slice to make a copy. if you
// don't make a copy, items will be removed from content.children each time appendChild is called,
// which will mess up the loop iteration
var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(content.children);
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  $contentToReplace.get(0).appendChild(children[i]);
}
```

You can check out how they did it in [Canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/canvg.js) - just search for the parseXml method.

You can also pass in different [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to the parseFromString method. The browser support on those varies a bit though - for example, the 'image/svg+xml' MIME type isn't supported in IE9 or earlier.

Changing the MIME type just changes what type of document you get back. Using 'text/xml' gives back an XMLDocument, which appears to work fine in this case.